# Typing an object key with same variants of an interface attribute

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How can I turn an interface attribute variants in required exact object keys?

Something like this:

```
interface ITest {
    colorVariant: 'default' | 'primary' | 'secondary'
}

//Correct
const colorVariantList: Pick<ITest, 'colorVariant'> = {
    default: 'test'
    primary: 'test2',
    secondary: 'test3',
}

//Error
const colorVariantList: Pick<ITest, 'colorVariant'> = {
    default: 'test'
    primary: 'test2',
}

//Error
const colorVariantList: Pick<ITest, 'colorVariant'> = {
    default: 'test'
    primary: 'test2',
    potato: 'test3',
}
```

Comment: `Record<ITest["colorVariant"], string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To access a key inside an interface you can use square bracket notation:

```js
interface ITest {
    colorVariant: 'default' | 'primary' | 'secondary'
}

type ColorVariant = ITest["colorVariant"]
```

2. To define an object with keys equal to the values of a union type, you can use a [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type):

```js
type ColorVariant = 'default' | 'primary' | 'secondary'

const colorVariantList: Record<ColorVariant, string> = {
    default: 'test',
    primary: 'test2',
    secondary: 'test3',
}
```

In the example above, the object is defined as a mapping from each of the values in the `ColorVariant` union type to a string.

3. Combining the two ideas together:

```js
const colorVariantList: Record<ITest["colorVariant"], string> = {
    default: 'test',
    primary: 'test2',
    secondary: 'test3',
}
```

See the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4BQyxyCA9gDZlQBqcUwc4AXMgOQAmE8ArhWG2QAfdgAcGAW3oBPQSLZYI5EBxlsCAXwIEA9DuQBhalCVgCynKUrU6DJmAAywHAHkA1qwBKS6hwA8GNhgANoARORUtPSM4KEAugA0yDgMIADmAHzIALz4RCRcvPysbJA4bAn5xOLAUlDSJWVgAEwVVck%20KjKNQQDMbVq6%20gCiUFDU5mQglhE20fZOOAByZGB0FMAcAIxePlD%20gThhs1F2sYnJYKmZOXkkyIVwfGA95ZX3NXUN7E2tlYN6ZCjcZQSbTXAnWwxRzOMArNZwDYcZq7cj7AKYI7haynaHxJIpUA3W6Ee6PZ6vATvEifbo-IJ-dqiVZwMBkSn9f5AA) for a full example.